# Upload automatically to iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, icloud

I have a application that performs file upload to iCloud. I have placed a button when tapped the files will be uploaded. I have no problem in uploading file to iCloud by a button press. Is there any way to upload files automatically to iCloud or In a timely manner ?

Answer (score 0):

can you provide more information? your code for example? Because you can create a method to upload in iCloud and call it in some conditions, or in viewDidLoad.. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iCloud then your files should generally be uploaded when the user saves them or on autosave. E.g. pages, at certain intervals and when the app goes into the background the new document is uploaded to iCloud. (iCloud documents).

Assume that when your App normally saves data locally, that's when data should be pushed to iCloud if specified.

The iCloud user defaults and Core Data with iCloud need different approaches.